# Two change event codes needed in one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run two change events codes (I found them on different websites) in one worksheet. I’ve looked at a lot of examples and most seem to merge them in to one event. However I cannot work out how to do do that with mine (or even if I should).

The first code is to clear dependant drop down menus:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C13")) Is Nothing Then
Range("C14").ClearContents
End If

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C14")) Is Nothing Then
Range("C15").ClearContents
End If

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C13")) Is Nothing Then
Range("C17").ClearContents
End If

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C14")) Is Nothing Then
Range("M14").ClearContents
End If
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C13")) Is Nothing Then
Range("C15").ClearContents
End If

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C15")) Is Nothing Then
Range("C17").ClearContents
End If
```

The second code is to automatically enlarge a merged cell notes box on The worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MergeWidth As Single
Dim cM As Range
Dim AutoFitRng As Range
Dim CWidth As Double
Dim NewRowHt As Double
Dim str01 As String
str01 = "Note"
If Not Intersect(Target, Range(str01)) Is Nothing Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Set AutoFitRng = Range(Range(str01).MergeArea.Address)
With AutoFitRng
  .MergeCells = False
  CWidth = .Cells(1).ColumnWidth
  MergeWidth = 0
  For Each cM In AutoFitRng
      cM.WrapText = True
      MergeWidth = cM.ColumnWidth + MergeWidth
  Next
  'small adjustment to temporary width
MergeWidth = MergeWidth + AutoFitRng.Cells.Count *      0.66
  .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergeWidth
  .EntireRow.AutoFit
  NewRowHt = .RowHeight
  .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = CWidth
  .MergeCells = True
  .RowHeight = NewRowHt
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, one of my attempts made the notes box on the worksheet hidden as well just because it didn’t have anything entered in to it at the time, so i’m not sure if the second code needs adjusting.

Any help will be appreciated as I am completely new to VBA, and just struggling to complete something at work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the merged (and slightly cleaned-up) code would look like:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MergeWidth As Single
Dim cM As Range
Dim AutoFitRng As Range
Dim CWidth As Double
Dim NewRowHt As Double

    ' Check once if we have more than one cell in the Target, if so, leave the sub:
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    ' Changes related to Target = C13:
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C13")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C14").ClearContents
        Range("C15").ClearContents
        Range("C17").ClearContents
    End If

    ' Changes related to Target = C14:
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C14")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C15").ClearContents
        Range("M14").ClearContents
    End If

    ' Changes related to Target = C15:
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C15")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C17").ClearContents
    End If

    ' Changes related to Target = Range named "Note":
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Note")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Set AutoFitRng = Range(Range("Note").MergeArea.Address)
        With AutoFitRng
          .MergeCells = False
          CWidth = .Cells(1).ColumnWidth
          MergeWidth = 0
          For Each cM In AutoFitRng
              cM.WrapText = True
              MergeWidth = cM.ColumnWidth + MergeWidth
          Next
          'small adjustment to temporary width
          MergeWidth = MergeWidth + AutoFitRng.Cells.Count * 0.66
          .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = MergeWidth
          .EntireRow.AutoFit
          NewRowHt = .RowHeight
          .Cells(1).ColumnWidth = CWidth
          .MergeCells = True
          .RowHeight = NewRowHt
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

As for the part you mentioned re:making the notes box hidden, I'm not sure what you did, but this is just the 2 methods conglomerated. If they worked well separately, they should work just as well in the code above.

Also, just look at the changes I made to learn how / why they were possible - For example, you only need to check once if you have more than one cell in the target range since you'll leave the method at that point, so no need for checking more than that. Also, once you know which cell was affected, do all the changes related to that at once.

Hope this helps you understand better... VBA is definitely worthwhile getting to understand.

Comment: Hi John, Thank You so much for having a look at this.

Comment: @VBANewbie, my pleasure and welcome to SO - Let me know if something catches you up, but I hope the code became a bit easier to understand once we removed a lot of the repetition. Also, if it does work, remember to mark it as a solution so others know this worked for you.